# Python -> MySQL "select * from brand WHERE text='L\'Orial'" (quote inside search text)

Tags: python, sql

From Python 3.9 i'm trying to do a MySql query like this
select * from brand WHERE text='L\'Orial'.
It works fine from phpMyAdmin but fails from python for all text including quote "'"

```
brand = "L'Orial"
where = f"text='{brand}'"
brand_pk_id = self.getPrimaryKeyIfExistInTable('brand', where)

def getPrimaryKeyIfExistInTable(self, table, where, key='id'):
   try:
      sql = f"SELECT {key} FROM {table} WHERE {where}"
      self.cursor.execute(sql)
      result = self.cursor.fetchone()
      return result[key if self.bUseDictCursor else 0] if result else None
   except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
      logging.error(e)
   return None
```

I can see that python escapes all quotes, which probably causes the problem, but can not figure out how to handle it properly !!

If I turn it around and use query LIKE with underscore( _ ) as wildcard:

```
brand = "L_Orial"
sql = f"SELECT {key} FROM {table} WHERE text LIKE '{brand}'"
```

It works fine, but this is not what I want !!

Comment: You should not use `f strings` to insert parameters in your queries or your app will be vulnerable to SQL injections.  Can you try this:
 
`sql = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s"
self.cursor.execute(sql, (key, table, where))`

Comment: @May.D, I don't think parameters are to be used for column names or table names; these are only to be used for values.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel To my understanding parameters should be used to escape any variable in a query.

Comment: @May.D then we agree to disagree.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I could not found anything in mysql connector documentation but you can have a look at pyscopg2's documentation (modules are very similar)
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#sql-injection

Comment: @May.D, the page you linked to does not give one example of using parameters to replace table names or column names, only values.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel This quote seems quite clear to me > Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Comment: I never suggested using string concatenation. Have you ried what you've suggested? From 20+ years of development, parameters are for values and not table names or column names. But hey, what do I know?

Comment: I do not care about sql injection for this code as it is for internal use only when parsing internal data etc. 
But on the backend code (php) I use bind_param() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, your problem is as follows:

Your query must exactly read:

```
SELECT * from brand WHERE text='L\'Orial'
```

But you are currently getting something like this, when you use python to execute the query:

```
SELECT * from brand WHERE text='L'Orial'
```

If this is indeed the issue, you should be able to resolve this by simply escaping the backslash that you need to have in the query. The complete python string for your query would be:

```py
# Python String:
"SELECT * from brand WHERE text='L\\'Orial'"
# Resulting Query
SELECT * from brand WHERE text='L\'Orial'
```

If you wanted to automatically fix this issue for all brands that might include a `'`, you can simply `replace` the `'` with `\\'` before making the query. Example:

```py
brand = "L'Orial"
brand = brand.replace("'", "\\'")

# New Python string:
#   "L\\'Orial"
# Output in SQL
#   "L\'Orial"
```

Comment: Ok .. meaning that this would solve the problem
 
``
brand = "L'Orial"

brand = brand.replace("'", "\\'")
``

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should, yes.

Comment: Thanks .. we got the exact same solution :-)

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, remember to make your question as answered, so that others can benefit from the information as well!

Comment: How do I "make it answered" ?
Do you want me to append the solution in the question  ?

Comment: You want to [click the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) next to the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Had to fire up my local instance just to make a point.

First, some prep work...

```py
import pymysql

table = 'ps_carrier'
key = 'id_carrier'

mysql = {
        "charset": "utf8",
        "database": "mystore",
        "host": "localhost",
        "password": "secret",
        "user": "justin"
    }
```

As somebody suggested in the comments, the following

```py
sql = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s"
where = "name='UPS'"
with pymysql.connect(**mysql) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql, (key, table, where))
```

Raises an error as expected since **all** the (string) params are quoted, **even the table name!**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>

...

  File "C:\Python38\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''ps_carrier' WHERE 'name=\\'UPS\\''' at line 1")
```

If you can trust the inputs for the table name, the key, and the column name(s) then perhaps a simple query builder can help.

```py
params = {'name': 'UPS'} # add more key--value pairs here

# use backticks in case we need to escape reserved words (OP uses MySQL)
where = " AND ".join(f"`{k}` = %s" for k in params.keys())  # .keys() just to be explicit
args = tuple([v for v in params.values()])

# backticks again
sql = f"SELECT `{key}` FROM `{table}` WHERE {where}"

print(sql)
print(args)

with pymysql.connect(**mysql) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql, args)
        print(cur.fetchall())
```

If you need something more elaborate, there are a few modules such as [Mysql Simple Query Builder](https://mysqlsimplequerybuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [PyPika - Python Query Builder](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that you may want to look at (I've not used any of these.)